# Display unique node using views in drupal

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views

I am trying to display latest articles using `views` module. There are 12 article should be displayed per click of pagination excluding the duplicate entry. So, I tried as:

- checked `Advanced > Query settings > Distinct` but no luck.
- I have also tried as `Views Distinct Settings > Filter/Aggregate this field > Filter Repeat`, it works but number of articles are displayed less than 12.

Then, I tried to do it using the hook `mymodule_views_query_alter` but I do not understand how can I accomplish this task. I tried as:

```
if($view->current_display == "latest_article"){
    $query->add_groupby('node.title');
}
```

But no solution. How can I override the `query` and inject `DISTINCT` function to get unique record.

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried using **Use aggregation** option from **Advanced** section ? Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes I did but when I enable `aggregation`, none of content is displayed.

Comment: Even with no query alteration nor other options enabled from your initial post ?